# Hide part of text temporarily, show after user clicks certain element

Tags: c#, text, htmlelements

I'm making a detail page about certain items.
This detail page can contain large blocks of text, and the customer would like to only show the first 100 letters and then put a " ... more " at the end.

When the user clicks this " ... more " the rest of the text can be shown.

Biggest problem: the text is currently is a CMS and has large varieties. Some is pure text, some have html elements in them ...

I tried to cut off the text and put them in spans. Then i could show/hide these spans as i please. The issue here is that there can be a starting element of a certain tag in the first span and the closing element can be in the second span. This causes the DOM hierarchyto be faulty and the result is never pretty.

Does anyone know a ( other ) way to achieve this or a library i can use ?

Comment: Does the text really need to be cut, or is it just a display issue? If second, then why not just put the text in a <div> and configure overflow so the rest of the text is not displayed, then add a "more ..." link which expands the div?

Comment: Is the requirement to show 100 characters based on the amount of information contained therein or based on the real-estate used by it on screen?

Comment: This would have one of the same issues. Say there is a <p> element in the first <div> but the </p> element is in the second <div>. This would not work.

( It would work fine if the text didn't already come with html elements )

Comment: @NicoE It's a random value

Answer (score 0):

To be able to extract "readable" characters you need to get the content into a plain text format (get rid of the mark-up).

Since the content is stored in a cms it is likely that the content is structured to be well formed - thus xhtml.
If that is the case you can treat the content as XML.  Get the root node and get the innertext property there-of. Then you will have plain text - no tags - and can easily cut it after the first 100 characters or whatever the requirement is.

Hopefully the content doesn't contain js/css!

**Edit:**
It seems that the markup must be retained.
Try the following xsl to transform and truncate the content:
https://gist.github.com/allen/65817

Comment: Well yes, but then i lose the markup like bold lines and paragraphs right ? This won't be acceptable i'm afraid

Comment: I've edited the answer with a link to some xsl code which you could possibly build on to solve the problem according to your requirements